# How to resolve *** missing separator. when compiling QT (or supporting libraries)?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, libqxt

When compiling QXT for Windows (following [these instructions](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/user_guide)) I receive the following errors from Makefile.Debug when running "make" from the command line:

```
*** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I had been using QT to generate Visual Studio project files and am not sure why this is happening.

This also can happen with supporting libraries such as quazip or whenever you are using qmake to generate Makefiles on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to verify your QMAKESPEC is set appropriately. If you have been previously generating Visual Studio projects it will likely be set to this, make sure to change it to:

```
QMAKESPEC = QTDIR\mkspecs\win32-g++
```

or the Makefile will not be generated correctly.

See [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3865) for more information.

---

Part of my duty to help others avoid [this problem](http://xkcd.com/979/)